Why the C standard library haven't isequal?
C standard library have: isgreater,isgreaterequal,isless,islessequal,islessgreater, isunordered.
And why the C standard library haven't isequal? It should be easy to implement like that:
bool isequal(float x, float y)
{
    return !isunordered(x, y) && isgreaterequal(x, y) && !isgreater(x, y);
}


Whether two approximately equal floating point values should be considered equal is context specific. Related: Is floating-point == ever OK?

@WeatherVane: That is not relevant to this question. These macros are intended to assist ordering, as in sorting. They are not intended to perform any sort of “approximate” comparison. If any sort of “approximate” comparison were intended in these macros, it would affect all of them, not just isequal.

Being able to order things is a different class of problem than being able to test whether two items compare the same.

I think in most cases you don't need them to be exactly equal and can not expect them to be exactly equal. You can simple see cases like 0.03 + 0.01 + 0.02 != 0.03 + 0.02 + 0.01. In most cases what you check if abs(d1 - d2) < epsilon

I would think it is because these macros are defined as "silent" (non-exception-raising) counterparts of the regular relation operators, while == is silent anyway. Said that, there is a iseqsig function proposed by GNU library which does the opposite - behaves like == but throwing the exception: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/FP-Comparison-Functions.html

The C99 rationale V5.10 explains that these macros were added to the language for the sole purpose of being safe and not raising floating point exceptions, like their corresponding operators might do:

The relational operators (<, <=, >=, >), but not the equality operators (==
and !=), may raise floating-point exceptions when one of the operands is a NaN (as an error indicator for programs written without consideration of NaNs). There is a need for comparisons that are guareented [sic] not to raise any floating-point exceptions; this also is a requirment [sic] of IEC-60559. That is why the isgreater, isgreaterequal, isless, islessequal,
islessgreater and isunordered function-like macros were invented.


I know why haven't isequal now. And i test this is really work (as a side effect) :
bool isequal(float x, float y)
{
return !isunordered(x, y) && isgreaterequal(x, y) && !isgreater(x, y);
}
